# vaadin grid setTooltipGenerator not present in 23.3.1 ? in only pay?

Tags: vaadin

hello i ve used this or grid vaadin version 23.3.1 but the property setTooltipGenerator
is not present why?

```
grid.addColumn(person -> person.getName())
                .setTooltipGenerator(person -> "Age: " + getPersonAge(person))
                .setHeader("Birthday");
```

Comment: In my project this method is present. Are you sure you are using 23.3.1 and updated your IDE?

Answer (score 0):

It's there in the free version. Make sure you refresh your IDE after updating the Vaadin version. If you're using IntelliJ Idea and Maven, you'll want to click "Reload all Maven project" after updating the version number (even if you already ran `mvn install`).